# Thunar File Manager left side pane (tree view) configuration

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, customization, thunar

On Thunar 1.6, Xubuntu 16.0.5:

I don't know if it's possible, but why when I select a folder in *Thunar* on left side pane (tree view) and hit for example <kbd>g</kbd>, nothing happens. I would expect that the selection jumps to the first match of a folder or file beginning with a letter "g". This behavior works on right side pane (shortcuts view) as expected.

Another issue: selected folder on left side pane, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, also nothing happens, I have to hover the cursor over the expander, then left click to open it. Can I change these settings?

Comment: Regarding the folding issue: You can hit the right arrow key or **+** to unfold, and the left arrow or **-** to fold. Also, if you'd like to avoid having to use the mouse, you can cycle through the left side pane, the main area, and the address bar using **tab** and **shift** + **tab**.

Comment: Another hint: When you are in the left side pane, you can press **ctrl** + **f** to open the search function. From there you can select a folder as you do in the right side pane.

Comment: @StefanHamcke It's not working for me , I select a folder > ctrl+f > (type) Documents > NOTHING happens . What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: PS: folder selected contains folder Documents, after typing Documents I hit enter.

Comment: When the focus is on the left side pane and you hit ctrl+f, do you see a small input field appearing? This is the case in my versions of thunar, which are 1.6.11 on Debian, and 1.6.15 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I see this field and I type the direct. name to be searched then hit enter and this input field closes with no results.

Comment: That's weird. On my system, I can type a string and Thunar dynamically selects the first entry starting with that string, the same way as it works in the right side pane.

Comment: Note that the field disappears after a few seconds, are you sure it was still visible when you started typing?

Comment: I got it ! I must have to select the folder and EXPAND it to work. when the folder selected is not expanded it does not work, why ?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I somehow assumed you had the folder expanded. The search is only on the names of items currently shown on the side pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are on the left side pane, you may search for a folder via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>. A small field appears and you can type a search string. Thunar dynamically selects the first entry among all items shown in the pane that starts with the string (see image). The same works on the right pane, but there you don't need to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> but can type right away (unless you want to search for a file starting with a space, since that key opens the selected file).

In the left pane, you can hit <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>+</kbd> to unfold, and <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> to fold. Also, if you'd like to avoid having to use the mouse, you can cycle through the left side pane, the main area, and the address bar using <kbd>⇆</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>⇆</kbd>.

[image]